# Adding fonts for Joomla menu from google API

Tags: css, fonts, joomla, menu

I use Joomla v3.9.8 stable on my website with a template named AS002066 and i want to use some additional fonts provided by the google API.

I found some code in a file from my template called 'fonts.php' and added there code as it is written for other fonts from google too.
I also added the needed code in 'mod_as_menu.xml' but nothing does work. 
May i missed some thing?

This is what i added to my fonts.php. It's the same sheme like the entrys brought by the template:

```
 case 'UnifrakturCook':

        $font_arr['fontlink'] = "<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=UnifrakturCook&subset=latin,cyrillic,greek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";

        $font_arr['fontfamily'] = "font-family: 'UnifrakturCook', Arial, serif !important;";

        break;
```

And here what i added to my mod_as_menu.xml:

```
  <option value="UnifrakturCook">Google:UnifrakturCook</option>
```

But it doesn't matter what i choose. It will not change any font.
I hope someone can help me with this.